# preg_replace multiple-replace bugs

Tags: php, regex, replace

I am trying to make a function that renames file after they have been uploaded but this function doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Here is simple example code :

```
echo $pathinfo["filename"]."<br/>";
$pathinfo["filename"] = preg_replace('/[ÝŶŸỲỸỶỴ]/', "Y", $pathinfo["filename"]);
echo $pathinfo["filename"]."<br/>";
```

Which outputs :

```
JPEG xè.w_.a(m)aaỶle_oui_
JPEG xY�.w_.a(m)aaYYYle_oui_
```

è is transformed into ?? And Ỷ becomes YYY !?

I really don't understand why I don't have 'JPEG xè.w_.a(m)aaYle_oui_'.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `u` modifier to your regex if you want to grab Unicode characters.

```
echo $pathinfo["filename"]."<br/>";
$pathinfo["filename"] = preg_replace('/[ÝŶŸỲỸỶỴ]/u', "Y", $pathinfo["filename"]);
echo $pathinfo["filename"]."<br/>";
```